Issues with importing an installed library (Opensea API) with npx?
I am trying to run this Opensea get-events API example locally.
node -v
v18.20.4

npm list
└── (empty)

npx api install "@opensea/v2.0#45iy1ilxxofiw1"

── @api/opensea@2.0.0 -> ./.api/apis/opensea
├── @apidevtools/swagger-methods@3.0.2 extraneous
├── @babel/code-frame@7.24.7 extraneous
├── @babel/helper-validator-identifier@7.24.7 extraneous
├── @babel/highlight@7.24.7 extraneous
├── @babel/runtime@7.25.0 extraneous
├── @exodus/schemasafe@1.3.0 extraneous
├── @humanwhocodes/momoa@2.0.4 extraneous
├── @jsdevtools/ono@7.1.3 extraneous
├── @nodelib/fs.scandir@2.1.5 extraneous
├── @nodelib/fs.stat@2.0.5 extraneous
├── @nodelib/fs.walk@1.2.8 extraneous
├── @readme/better-ajv-errors@1.6.0 extraneous
... (omitted)
├── webidl-conversions@3.0.1 extraneous
├── whatwg-fetch@3.6.20 extraneous
├── whatwg-url@5.0.0 extraneous
├── which@2.0.2 extraneous
├── wrap-ansi@7.0.0 extraneous
├── y18n@5.0.8 extraneous
├── yaml@1.10.2 extraneous
├── yargs-parser@21.1.1 extraneous
├── yargs@17.7.2 extraneous
└── yarn@1.22.22

This is the project directory structure

Under the opensea_testing (root project directory), I created a test.js which I copied from the Opensea example above.
import opensea from '@api/opensea';

opensea.auth('opensea-api-key');
opensea.list_events()
  .then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

When I tried to run it with node test.js, I am getting this error derived from issue seemingly coming from the import statement.
(node:37112) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/mnt/c/PeterHunt/My_Blockchain_Dev/learning/tut_setup_nodejs_project/src/opensea_testing/test.js:1
import opensea from "@api/opensea";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:76:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1283:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1328:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

This is the package.json, I have added the "type": "module", but it resulted in the same error message.
I am new to node.js development and I am confused how the library installation. Especially, why is there package.json file in my main project directory, and another package.json under the opensea_testing.api\opensea directory?
